# iPhone passcode lock mechanism

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I develop the custom screen unlock for iPhone as the one working in case of passcode lock active mode?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about your question. Are you trying to develop a replacement for the custom unlock screen, or are you just trying to emulate the slider/passcode in your own app?

The former isn't possible. Apple will only allow the development of applications that are launched on-demand by the user: you cannot overwrite any of the things that Apple has developed.

As for the latter, I'm sure it's possible. Please try to be more clear exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: thanks for the guidance for of all.
My question was more concerned with the architectures perspective of the iphone's locking mechanism. As if we talk about the windows, we know there is GINA system working that is controlling the user authentication mechanism (via LAP) so is in mac it is done using the authentication services API but in iphone there is no authentication services API so i want to know how is the authentication process handled in iphone ?

Comment: secondly i am not trying to develop my custom application i know it is not possible i am trying to reuse the funtionality of the iphone's authentication process, you can say overriding it. 
I am actually developing an application that will use the bluetooth (taking the RSSI value from BT device say headset) and determine whether to lock or unlock the iphone. moreover, the application will also be running in the background even if it is inactive . 
So, rite now at this step i am interested in how the current system of iphone authentication is working and how can i use to develop  my app??

Comment: @maddy, You could create your View with a textfield for passcode, and compare the passcode with the one stored in your protected storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like the pin pad that shows up on 1password look at the UIApplicationDelegate protocol's `applicationWillResignActive:` and `applicationDidBecomeActive:` methods. These will be called when the iPhone is locked or unlocked respectively. You could then use them to switch the current view to an unlock  pin pad type view of your own design.